# How to log seconds only, without milliseconds in Phoenix Logger?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

The Phoenix Logger prints:

```
03:43:04.377 request_id=xxx [info] Sent 200 in 3ms
```

How to make it to omit milliseconds and print:

```
03:43:04 request_id=xxx [info] Sent 200 in 3ms
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can customize your logger output by trying to add something like this to your [configuration](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/configuration):

`config :logger, :console, format: "$time $metadata[$level] $levelpad$message\n"`

but... regrettably for you as I look in to the documentation of the [Logger](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/logger/Logger.html) and more specific at the [Logger.Formatter Types](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/logger/Logger.Formatter.html#types) it does not support a time format without the milliseconds.

You could try to add such support to the [Elixir Logger library](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/tree/master/lib/logger) by yourself or use a custom logger.